# Python Pandas - group by, count with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of data with site names and whether a given investigation closed as "On Time" or "Overdue". I want to figure out how to do a .groupby such that I can see the number of overdue investigations per site.

```
0  site_name        overdue
1  "Puerto Rico"    "Overdue"
2  "Paris"          "On Time"
3   "Puerto Rico"   "On Time"
4   "Paris"         "Overdue"
5   "Puerto Rico"   "On Time"
6   "Paris"         "Overdue"
```

Ideal output:

```
0    site_name     overdue_count
1    Puerto Rico     1
2    Paris           2
```

Comment: The expected output is ambiguous, what if you had several rows for "Puerto Rico"? would you want one row or as many as in the input?

Comment: Anyway it's either `df['overdue'].eq('Overdue').groupby(df['site_name']).agg(overdue_count='sum')` or `df['overdue_count'] = df['overdue'].eq('Overdue').groupby(df['site_name']).transform('sum')`

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question to make the output less ambiguous.

Comment: Then `df['overdue'].eq('Overdue').groupby(df['site_name']).agg(overdue_count='sum').reset_index()`